# Upload image to the server with the form data in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, http, multipartform-data, form-data

i using the ImagePicker package in the dart when i pick the image i want to upload this to the server with the form data but when i try to send this i give this error

***" Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'File: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.aloteb/files/Pictures/scaled_image_picker3594752094355545880.jpg'' "***
and this is my code for sending to the server

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.fields.addAll({
  'data': '$map'
});
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image',picproviderformdate.getPAth.toString()));
request.headers.addAll(headers);
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}

else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

and this is my ImagePickercode

```
picprovider pic = Provider.of<picprovider>(context,listen: false);
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
    print(_image);
    pic.setpathe(_image);
```

can any one help me for solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago, and i used the [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) dependency instead of the classical Http link.

The code is very similar, and i can gave you an example.

```dart
final File file = File("${documentDirectory.path}/picture.png");

  final httpDio = dio.Dio();
  final formData = dio.FormData.fromMap({
    "data": "{}",
    "files.image": await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(
        "${documentDirectory.path}/picture.png",
        filename: "picture.png",
        contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'))
  });

  try {
    final dio.Response response = await httpDio.post(
        "ApiEndpoint/avatars",
        data: formData,
        options: dio.Options(headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer yourTokenIfNeeded"}));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Success
    }
  } on dio.DioError catch (e) {
    if (e.response != null) {
      // Error
      print(e.response.data);
      return;
    }
  }
```

Don't forgot to update the API endpoint and route as well as your auth authorization if you need one.